# How to translate vexing 'for' loop into 'Object.keys' routine or similar (JSLint)

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, foreach, jslint

I'm attempting to follow the "best practices" of JSLint, which discourages `for` loops, recommending `Object.keys` and similar in their place. Most `for` loops are easily translatable to `Object.keys` with `forEach`, like this:

```
Object.keys(object).forEach(function (key) {
```

etc.

And a real-world example as here:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('myClass');
Object.keys(elems).forEach(function (key) {
    elems[key].style.display = 'block';
    elems[key].style.visibility = 'visible';
});
```

However, I'm flummoxed how to translate the following routine into a form that does not make use of a standard `for` loop.

```
var selection = window.getSelection();
var htmlDiv = document.createElement("div");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < selection.rangeCount; ++i) {
    htmlDiv.appendChild(selection.getRangeAt(i).cloneContents());
}
```

I don't need to iterate over `window.getSelection()`; I need to grab the text by ranges using the native `getRangeAt()` function of `window.getSelection()`.

Any clues how to do this without using a standard `for` loop as above?

Comment: Wait, what?? JSLint is saying to use `Object.keys` instead of a normal `for` loop? Because `Object.keys` is more performant? That makes no sense.

Comment: Could substitute `while` loop for `for` loop, or utilize `Array.prototype.forEach()`

Comment: Yes, JSLint discourages 'for' loops, and provides a rationale. See: http://www.jslint.com/help.html#for

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'll be a monkey's uncle. Misled by JSLint's prescription of 'Object.keys' in place of 'for' (see: [jslint.com/help.html#for](http://jslint.com/help.html#for)), the suggestion by @guest271314 to use a simple 'while' loop did the trick and passed JSLint's standards:

```
while (i < selection.rangeCount) {
    htmlDiv.appendChild(selection.getRangeAt(i).cloneContents());
    i += 1;
}
```

JSLint also insists on 'i += 1;' instead of `i++;` and provides a rationale (see http://www.jslint.com/help.html#inc ). But they don't explain why a `while` loop is a-okay compared with a 'for' loop; anyone care to speculate?